# how to save multiple custom fields for a post in one go?

Tags: custom-field, customization

I want to save multiple custom fields for a custom post in one go. Something like get_post_custom() except for that I need to set it this time.

Answer (score 2):

Custom post meta data are generally updated in the database via a callback function hooked into `save_post`. (Others: `draft_post`, `publish_post`, `future_post`.)

The custom post meta data are part of the `$_POST` data sent on-submit for the edit post screen, so simply look for them there, sanitize them, and then update them in the database.

I'm omitting things like nonce-checking and sanitizing `$_POST` data. You'll want to incorporate them into your callback as necessary.

For example:

```
function wpse63622_save_custom_post_metadata() {
    // Globalize $post
    global $post;

    // Find custom post meta data in $_POST
    // DON'T FORGET TO SANITIZE
    $custom_post_meta_1 = ( isset( $_POST['_custom_meta_key_1'] ) ? $_POST['_custom_meta_key_1'] : false );
    $custom_post_meta_2 = ( isset( $_POST['_custom_meta_key_2'] ) ? $_POST['_custom_meta_key_2'] : false );
    $custom_post_meta_3 = ( isset( $_POST['_custom_meta_key_3'] ) ? $_POST['_custom_meta_key_3'] : false );

    // Update the database
    if ( $custom_post_meta_1 ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_meta_key_1', $custom_post_meta_1 );
    }
    if ( $custom_post_meta_2 ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_meta_key_2', $custom_post_meta_2 );
    }
    if ( $custom_post_meta_3 ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_meta_key_3', $custom_post_meta_3 );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse63622_save_custom_post_metadata' );
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse63622_save_custom_post_metadata' );
```

Comment: Does every update_post_meta() query the database each time?

Comment: Coz my site is going to be heavy and I am optimizing and reducing unnecessary querying. So I was wondering if I could somehow put all the meta key-value pairs in an array and then update thw whole thing together. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "*Does every update_post_meta() query the database each time?*" - Each time *what*?

Comment: Does it save the meta value to the database and come back at every execution of the function?

Comment: Yes, every time you save or publish that post, the post custom meta data will be updated. Just like all of the rest of the data for the `$post` object.

Comment: OK..So when I click on "Publish", the function wpse63622_save_custom_post_metadata() executes once and the update_post_meta()s execute thrice as three of them are there. So pardon me for being repetitive I guess, does it mean that those three update_post_meta() calls are three calls to the database apart from the rest of the data for the $post object ?

Comment: That about sums it up. You've got three different post custom meta keys, so each one needs to be updated in the database. That action will in no way slow your site down, or pose any significant performance hit.

Comment: Thanks :) . But just for curiosity's sake, does every such function that gets or sets some value in the DB, make a separate call to the DB?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly: yes. Both [`update_option( $option, $value )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and [`update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) update a *single value* to the DB. You can get around that limitation for options by using the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).